# Docker link to connect nginx and php containers

Tags: docker

I tried to learn a (even though a bit outdated) form of linking containers. I created an NGINX and PHP container, which should get linked. Everything runs on my local machine.

**Dockerfile NGINX**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER Sebastian Scharf

# Install NGINX
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx \
    # Clean after apt-get
    && apt-get clean \
    ## remove content from apt/lists and var/tmp
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
    ## set deamon off
    && echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

ADD default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

# forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

CMD ["nginx"]
```

**Dockerfile PHP**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER Sebastian Scharf

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y locales \
    && locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl zip unzip git software-properties-common \
    && add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php7.0-fpm php7.0-cli php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql \
       php7.0-pgsql php7.0-imap php-memcached php7.0-mbstring php7.0-xml php7.0-curl \
    && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && mkdir /run/php \
    && apt-get remove -y --purge software-properties-common \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

ADD php-fpm.conf /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf
ADD www.conf /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm7.0"]
```

**NGINX CONFIG**

```
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name _;

    charset utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { log_not_found off; access_log off; }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

When I call localhost:8080, I get the error: This page isn't working (localhost didn't send any data). I was expecting to see a test file.

This is how I started the containers and linked them:

```
docker run -d --name=myphp -v $(pwd)/application:/var/www/html retronexus/php:0.1.0

docker run -d --link=myphp:php -p 8080:80 -v $(pwd)/application:/var/www/html retronexus/nginx:0.2.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx in your container listens on port 8080, but you are binding port 80 from the container to 8080 on the host. Switch to binding 8080 from the container.

```
docker run -d \
    --link=myphp:php \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    -v $(pwd)/application:/var/www/html \
    retronexus/nginx:0.2.0
```

See here for more details: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports